# Php preg_replace trocar src de imagem

Tags: php, regex

Gostaria de saber acrescentar a url do site na frente do src ja existente de todas as imagems de uma string exemplo:

```
<img src="images/teste.jpg" border="0" width="486" height="370" style="margin: 5px; float: left;" />
<img src="images/teste2.jpg">
```

para:

```
<img src="www.meusite.com/images/teste.jpg" border="0" width="486" height="370" style="margin: 5px; float: left;" />
<img src="www.meusite.com/images/teste2.jpg">
```

Qual expressão regular posso usar para isso?

Comment: Não é bom você fazer isso em tempo de execução, pois vai cair muito o despenho.

Tente criar uma constante URL_IMG com o endereço do site, depois junto com a ferramenta de edição substitua <img src=" por <img src="<?= URL_IMG ?>
Acho que isso vai revolver.

Comment: O problema é que só tenho uma string com o html, preciso alterar em cima da string, pois estou montando um serviço.

Comment: Esse img src vem de alguma string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se te ajudaria, mas você pode tentar da seguinte forma, talvez seria uma solução... Como não compreendi muito bem como você gostaria, e se a `url` vem de alguma `string` mas se vier, pode tentar assim:

```
$img = "<img src='teste.jpg' border='0'>";
$add_url = "http://www.google.com.br";
$str_image = explode("'", $img);
$new_image = "<img src='{$add_url}/{$str_image[1]}'>";
echo $new_image;
```

Se der um  `print_r` no `$str_image` retornaria o seguinte:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <img src=
    [1] => teste.jpg
    [2] =>  border=
    [3] => 0
    [4] => >
)
```

E com echo no `$new_image`:

```
<img src='http://www.google.com.br/teste.jpg'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Não precisa nem de preg_replace.

```
$html = '<img src="images/teste.jpg" border="0" width="486" height="370" style="margin: 5px; float: left;" /><img src="images/teste2.jpg">';

echo str_replace('<img src="','<img src="http://www.meusite.com/',$html);
```